# How to go back from IVec back to String?

Tags: rust

If IVec was created with:

```
sled::IVec::from("VAL1")
```

How do I get back to "VAL1"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get back to "VAL1", by doing the following:

```
let iv = IVec::from("VAL1");
let val = std::str::from_utf8(iv.as_ref()).unwrap();
```

You can find documentation for the AsRef trait here:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/convert/trait.AsRef.html#tymethod.as_ref

And as @Jmb astutely indicated, IVec implements [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/ops/trait.Deref.html) as well as the AsRef trait. Consequently, you can just do the following to get back to "VAL1" (omitting as_ref()):

```
let val = std::str::from_utf8 (&iv).unwrap();
```

Comment: Note that `sled::IVec` implements [`Deref<Target=[u8]>`](https://docs.rs/sled/latest/sled/struct.IVec.html#impl-Deref), so you can just do `std::str::from_utf8 (&iv).unwrap()`. No need for the explicit `as_ref`.